# php new class object not being instanced

Tags: php

I am trying to create a new model object from my mvc controller but the page doesn't generate. Is there any reason why I can't do this? Surely I should be able to create an object inside an existing one?

Sorry to be so simplistic, and I know I sound like an idiot, but I'm not sure how to explain what I am doing wrong.

```
class controller_landing extends controller_base
{
    public function __construct($get,$post)
    {
        parent::__construct($get,$post);

        $this->model = new model_landing;  <-----problem line here
    }
}

abstract class controller_base
{   
    //store headers
    protected $get;
    protected $post;

    //store layers
    protected $view;
    protected $model;

    protected function __construct($get,$post)
    {    
        //store the header arrays
        $this->get = $get;
        $this->post = $post;

        //preset the view layer as an array
        $this->view = array();
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        //extract variables from the view layer
        extract($this->view);

        //render the view to the user
        require_once('view/'.$this->get['controller'].'_view.php');
    }
}

class model_landing extends class_mysqli
{
    public function __construct
    {
        echo "landing model";   
    }
}

class class_mysqli
{
    public function __construct
    {
        echo "mysqli";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your problem here is. The code above works fine on my machine and it outputs the content from the viewer. This also seems to be working right with phpfiddle http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vhy-ecw. What version of php are you using and, perhaps, if you could show any error_log if any?

Comment: maybe the problem is in the autoloader then somehow..ty anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t know, but I think you are missing brackets.
There

```
public function __construct
{
        echo "landing model";  
}
```

should be

```
public function __construct()
{
        echo "landing model";   
}
```